# How to install a previous stable version of a Rails 3 gem from GitHub?

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have to install a gem (liquid) from Git. But currently in the GitHub page it has a alpha version and I need to install a previous stable version of it.

How can I set up Bundle for that? I'm on Rails 3.

My bundle command is:

```
gem 'liquid','2.2.2' ,:git => 'git://github.com/GnomesLab/liquid.git'
```

and I'm running:

```
bundle pack
```

and the error is:

```
Could not find gem 'liquid (= 2.2.2, runtime)' in git://github.com/GnomesLab/liquid.git (at master).
Source contains 'liquid' at: 2.3.0.alpha
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is looking at master regardless of what version you specify after the gem name.  You can specify a tag after the git project and it should work:

```
gem 'liquid', :git => 'git://github.com/GnomesLab/liquid.git', :tag=>"v2.2.2"
```

Comment: no problem.  Just so ya know, you can also specify a commit hash from git if there is no tag in the repo.